# What is the difference between '('() 2 3) and '(() 2 3) in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, quote

I just found out, that:

```lisp
(null? (car '('() 2 3)))
```

returns **false**, and:

```lisp
(null? (car '(() 2 3)))
```

returns **true**.

What's the difference between this two formats?

Comment: Is there no difference between `(car '('() 2 3))` and `(car '(() 2 3))` in your REPL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that `'X` is just an abbreviation for the two element list: `(quote X)`.

So `(car '(() 2 3))` is an abbreviation for `(car (quote (() 2 3)))`, while `(car '('() 2 3)))` is an abbreviation for `(car (quote ((quote ()) 2 3)))`.

Since `(quote something)` evaluates to `something`, when the system evaluates `(car (quote ((quote ()) 2 3)))` the first step of evaluation produces: `(car ((quote ()) 2 3))`. And the `car` of that list produces its first element, that is `(quote ())`.

So it is not null, and the result is false.

Comment: *So it is not null, and result is true.* isn't it the converse? (But explanation is correct)